# Is it possible to run a Linux server distro on an old phone?

Tags: phone, smartphone

I have an old Xiaomi mi 9 Lite (pyxis) with a custom android rom installed.

The CPU is the Qualcomm Snapdragon 710 ([all specs](https://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_mi_9_lite-9862.php))

I've already discovered [Ubuntu Touch](https://ubuntu-touch.io), but it comes with a desktop environment and my Phone is not suported.

I also looked at [Ubuntu Server for ARM](https://ubuntu.com/download/server/arm) but can't find a way to use that.

[Arch Linux ARM](https://archlinuxarm.org/) isn't supported by the processor.

Maybe interesting for more research would be [Renegade Project](https://renegade-project.tech/en/porting) which was able to get Windows 11 running on a Smartphone with UEFI.

Do you have any idea how to use my old phone as a homeserver? I'm happy to learn anything  that goes in the right direction, even if it's just a small step towards a solution.

I have a lot of time for the project, but I'm a beginner, so if I have to create a own ROM I'd like you to help me with good learning sources.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert android phone into linux server(bare metal performance)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/669887/convert-android-phone-into-linux-serverbare-metal-performance)

Answer (score 0):

If your device [is supported](https://wiki.postmarketos.org/wiki/Devices) you could run PostmarketOS on it. If it is not in that list you could [try to port your own](https://wiki.postmarketos.org/wiki/Porting_to_a_new_device).

[postmarketOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostmarketOS) (abbreviated as pmOS) is an operating system primarily for smartphones, based on the Alpine Linux distribution.